# Ho do I get return column value from Lookup to insert into Oledb destination db?

Tags: c#, ssis, flat-file

I am very new to SSIS: my requirement is to load the flat file with some columns (planid, name, start date, agentid), in flat file name column having with null, this name value i have to take from another sql db by help of fetching flat file `planid`. Finally this all values get to be insert into Oledb destination DB.

I worked with Lookup transformation,to return name column value from other SQL DB at the time of mapping in oledb dest db, it's throwing some errors even I used data conversion task. I don't know whether I am going with correct way or not.

flat file having =

```
100|null|3552|12/25/2018|
```

Other db having with=

```
100|Name:Patsy|
```

target to insert into OLE DB destination db:

```
100|Name:Patsy|3552|12/25/2018|
```

Comment: Check the following link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/39184f06-80f7-4192-aa8f-a41708fd8a4c/how-to-do-a-lookup-only-when-input-column-is-null?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: I have tried in couple ways which were not solved my requirement t. So I had done using Script component task ,as usual inside connection string.